# Access a nested grand child component in a parent component

Tags: reactjs, components, parent, lifecycle, refs

I need to access 'GreatGrandChild' component in the 'View' component.

### View Component:

```
<View>
  <Child>
    ....
  </Child>
</View>
```

### Child Component:

```
<Child>
  <GrandChild>
      ....      
    </GrandChild>
</Child>
```

### GrandChild component:

```
<GrandChild>
  <GreatGrandChild>
    ....
  </GreatGrandChild>
</GrandChild>
```

### GreatGrandChild component:

```
<GreatGrandChild ref={(component) => { this.component = component; }}>
  ....
</GreatGrandChild>
```

How do I access the 'GreatGrandChild' component in the 'View' component?
Can I access it using refs? Which lifecycle method would be most appropriate in that case?

Comment: What is it you want to access? Its `state` or its DOM representation (i.e `ref`)?

Comment: DOM representation

Comment: why do you want to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular prop to pass your ref - but it must have a different name:

```
// somewhere in constructor
this.greatGrandChild = React.createRef();

<View>
  <Child greatGrandChildRef={this.greatGrandChild}>
    ....
  </Child>
</View>


<Child>
  <GrandChild greatGrandChildRef={this.props.greatGrandChildRef}>
      ....      
    </GrandChild>
</Child>


<GrandChild>
  <GreatGrandChild greatGrandChildRef={this.props.greatGrandChildRef}>
    ....
  </GreatGrandChild>
</GrandChild>

<GreatGrandChild ref={this.props.greatGrandChildRef}>
  ....
</GreatGrandChild>
```

This is very much the same idea of `innerRef` in `styled-components` and how they suggest it in React docs.

Comment: Hey Tomasz, what's the difference between this method and using React.forwardRef API?

Comment: @NaserMohdBaig it's a solution from the time when forwardRef API was not available.

Comment: So you'd recommend using forwardRef instead of this approach? This actually is more straightforward for my use case :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also emit from child to parent on each component
and if you need to check something from view in the greatgrandchild, you can do like this:

_____in view :

methods: {

updateValue(valueFromDown){

```
//you have access to the value from greatgranchild, it is valueFromDown
```

...

},

```
<Child :valueToSend="valueToSend" @updateValue='updateValue'>
    ....
</Child>
```

______in the child :

props : [ 'valueToSend',...

methods:{

```
     updateValue(value){
        this.$emit('updateValue', value);
    }
  },

<GrandChild :valueToSend="valueToSend" @updateValue='updateValue'>
      ....      
</GrandChild>
```

_____in the granchild:

props : [ 'valueToSend', ...

methods:{

```
    updateValue(value){

        this.$emit('updateValue', value);
    }
  },

<GreatGrandChild :valueToSend="valueToSend" @updateValue='updateValue'>
      ....      
</GreatGrandChild>
```

_____and in the GreatGrandChild :

props : [ 'valueToSend',...

methods:{

```
checkTheValue(){
```

//check...

this.$emit( 'updateValue', valueFromDown);
  // i think it is your this.component

}

```
<GreatGrandChild ref={(component) => { this.component = component; }}>
  ....
</GreatGrandChild>
```