# React forwardRef: How deep can you pass down forwardRef?

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-forwardref

I'm wondering how deep you can pass forwardRef down in a nested app, and how would someone pass it down?

Something like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    ....
  </Child>
</Parent>

    <Child>
      <GrandChild>
          ....      
      </GrandChild>
    </Child>

        <GrandChild>
          <GreatGrandChild>
            ....
          </GreatGrandChild>
        </GrandChild>

            <GreatGrandChild>
              ....
            </GreatGrandChild>
```

and then use it in GreatGrandChild component or passing down the ref of and element in Parent down to GreatGrandChild

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621471/access-a-nested-grand-child-component-in-a-parent-component

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a ref as deep as you want but that seems inefficient.

One alternative would be to use the context API to set a ref in the producer (component containing the ref element) and use it in the consumer (child that will utilize the ref)

Comment: How would you go about doing it with context? Sorry I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: FILE 1:
interface IValue extends PropsWithChildren {
  value: {
    mapRef: MutableRefObject<Map>;
  };
}

export const MapContext = createContext(null);

export const MapContextProvider = ({ children, value }: IValue) => (
  <MapContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</MapContext.Provider>
);

FILE 2:
const { mapRef } = useContext(MapContext);

FILE 3:
const mapRef = useRef<Map>();
<MapContextProvider value={{ mapRef }}>